# overflow-y not working with updating content

Tags: html, css

Momently I working on my Website. Since I changed the code for Updating the messages every 1,5 seconds , the **Scrollbar** was disabled and the **height** not working anymore.

There is a little preview :

```css
.chat-history {
    height:30%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

.message {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:#123;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-history">
  <p class="message">TEST</p>  
  <p class="message">TEST</p>
  <p class="message">TEST</p>
  <p class="message">TEST</p>
  <p class="message">TEST</p>
  <p class="message">TEST</p>
  <p class="message">TEST</p>
  <p class="message">TEST</p>
  <p class="message">TEST</p>
  <p class="message">TEST</p>
  <p class="message">TEST</p>
  <p class="message">TEST</p>
  <p class="message">TEST</p>
  <p class="message">TEST</p>
</div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/c66mx3nc/)

Answer (score 3):

The chat div needs to be in a container with a height attribute for the 30% height to be valid.

wrap your code in something like this:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='chat-history>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and add css (example):

```
.container {
   height: 600px; 
}
```

Alternatively, give your body a height. Or as stated in another answer, get rid of your relative height (as a %) and give it a definite height with a number of pixels.

https://jsfiddle.net/c66mx3nc/

Comment: @DanielO. was this sufficient to answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

A height needs to be set on the parent element so `height: 30%` is a valid calculation.

```css
* { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }

html { height: 100%; } /* required to make body's height work */
body { height: 100%; }

.chat-history {
  height:30%;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

.message {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:#123;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-history">
   <p class="message">TEST</p>  
   <p class="message">TEST</p>
   <p class="message">TEST</p>
   <p class="message">TEST</p>
   <p class="message">TEST</p>
   <p class="message">TEST</p>
   <p class="message">TEST</p>
   <p class="message">TEST</p>
   <p class="message">TEST</p>
   <p class="message">TEST</p>
   <p class="message">TEST</p>
   <p class="message">TEST</p>
   <p class="message">TEST</p>
   <p class="message">TEST</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to apply height in pixel.

```
    .chat-history {
   height:250px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
     }
```

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/c66mx3nc/3/

Comment: Sorry but I would like to do that with % and not with px